# How implement break in functional-like language

Tags: loops, break, language-design

Hi I am wondering what is a "best" way to implement break and continue in language, where loops statements eg. while and for, and if-statement are actually functions. 
So I think that break could throw exeption, Ruby-like but while-function catch it a automagically and stop looping.

example:

```
i = 0
while true, do
            i +
            if i > 10, break
end
```

There do..end block is param of while and also break is if's code parametre.

ps. sorry for language :/

Comment: what about `return`??

Comment: works it? if if function eval block where break is, how while can know that there is break? Or if return-statement is in if, so that break only evaluation of if-function?

Answer (score 0):

If you have discriminated unions (or a similar feature, like OOP inheritance) available, you could use that: an expression does may return not just the normal return value, but also special values for `break` and `continue`.

Or, using ML syntax (where `'a` is the type of the expression):

```ml
type 'a expression_result = Break | Continue | Return of 'a
```

If an expression does not return anything, you can use the `unit` type as `'a`.